# Is every finite group of odd order $n$ isomorphic to a subgroup of $A_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is it true that every finite group of odd order $n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $A_n$?

I used Cayley's theorem but couldn't proceed further. I am not getting whether n is the order of the group or not.
Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Most likely, $n$ is supposed to be the order of the group.  If not, then the assumption that the order of the group is odd is not necessary; every finite group is isomorphic to a subgroup of *some* alternating group.  (If the order is $n$, you can stick it inside $A_{n+2}$.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this is true: look at the homomorphism $\varphi: S_n \rightarrow C_2$, $\varphi(\sigma)=sign(\sigma)$. Then $ker(\varphi)=A_n$. The order of the image of your group $G$ (now seen as a subgroup of $S_n$ (Cayley)) is $|\varphi(G)|$ and by the isomorphism theorems, this number divides $|C_2|=2$ and divides $|G|$, which is *odd*. So $|\varphi(G)|=1$ and hence $G \subseteq ker(\varphi)$.

Answer (score 3):

Using Cayley's theorem is the way to go.
You can then consider that $G$ is a subgroup of $\mathfrak{S}_n$ for some $n$. But every element $g\in G$ has $g^{2k+1} = 1$ for some $k$. 
What does this imply on $\epsilon(g)$ ?

Comment: Sir I can't think what we can conclude about $\epsilon (g)$ from $g^{2k+1}=1$. I tried thinking in line of transpositions, but transpositions have order 2. e.g. odd permutation $(23)^{2k+1}=(23)$ as well as even permutation $((12)(34))^{2k+1}=(12)(34)$.

Comment: @Silent : If $g^{2k+1} =1$, then $\epsilon (g)^{2k+1}=1$. What are the values that $\epsilon (g)$ can take ?

Comment: If $\epsilon (g)^{2k+1}=1$ then $\epsilon(g)$ can't be -1. Hence 1. Am I correct about this: If $g^{2k+1} =1$ then $\epsilon (g)^{2k+1}=1$ because $\epsilon:S_n\to\{\pm1\}$ is a homomorphism ? Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: @Silent : yes that's it, because $(-1)^{2k+1}=-1$